# Вставка данных в базу данных MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

В общем друзья... Не могу увидеть ошибку в коде... Есть код ниже, который вставляет в базу id, name, series поля, но name всегда одинаковый. Вывод работает, но вставляет не так... Где то походу со скобками косяк...

```
$sqlGetContentId = mysql_query("SELECT episode.id, episode.parent_id 
FROM parser.episode  GROUP BY parent_id limit 10");

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT content.id, name, description, screenshot.url,
episode.smil, content_types.type_id
FROM parser.content, parser.screenshot, parser.episode, parser.content_types
WHERE screenshot.id = content.id
AND screenshot.size =  '768x432'
AND content.id = episode.id
AND content_types.content_id = content.id
LIMIT 10");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {

echo $id = $row['id'];

echo "<br>";
echo $name = $row['name'] . "\n";
echo "<br>";
echo $description = $row['description'] . "\n";
echo "<br>";
echo $url = $row['url'] . "\n";
echo "<br>";
echo $smilSelect = $row['smil'] . "\n";
echo "<br>";
echo $typesId = $row['type_id'] . "\n";
echo "<br>";
}

if ($sql == true) {

if ($sqlGetContentId == true) {

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlGetContentId)) {


        $newId = $row['id'];
        $contentId = $row['parent_id'];

        $sqlGetCount = mysql_query("SELECT count(episode_num) AS  
       counterContent FROM parser.episode  WHERE parent_id = $contentId");

        if ($sqlGetCount == true) {

            $row = mysql_fetch_row($sqlGetCount);


            if ($row[0] > 1) {


                $number = $row[0];
                $arr = range(1, $row[0]);
                echo $str = serialize($arr);
                $string = $str;
                echo "<br>";


                $inertFilm = mysql_query("INSERT INTO stalker_db.news (id, name, series)
                VALUES ('$newId', '$name', '$str')");

                         }

            if ($row[0] == 1) {


                $urlFilm = "http://main.itv.by/getsmil.php?season=0&episode=0&content=$id";
                $inertFilm = mysql_query("INSERT INTO stalker_db.news (id, name, series)
             VALUES ('$id', '$name', '$str')");
                echo "This is film: " . "\n";
                echo "<br>";


            }

        }

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так у Вас в цикле вставки нигде и не присваивается новое значение переменной `$name`, оставаясь всегда равным последнему выведенному значению.

Убедитесь, что Вы используете требуемые имена переменных в процессе вставки и не забываете присваивать им необходимые значения в цикле вставки.